# Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}[y]$ as rings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}[y]$ as rings?

Generally, in a category $\mathcal{C}$ with fibered product, morphisms $f: X\rightarrow Z$, $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, and $h: Z\rightarrow W$. when can say $X\times_Z Y\simeq X\times_W Y$?

Comment: Please see the FAQ for reasons why this question would be better at http://math.stackexchange.com, which is an excellent site for mathematics questions of this sort.

Comment: Seems to me the problem would be easier if you avoided the categorification.  You can see straight away that the constant terms in $\mathbb{C}[x] \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}[y]$ are $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$, which has dimension 4 over $\mathbb{R}$, and not 2 like $\mathbb{C}$ does.

Comment: Another direct approach: since $\mathbb{C}[x] \cong \mathbb{R}[x] \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$, by rearranging tensor products we can see that the right-hand side is $(\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C})[x,y]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well ${\bf C}[x,y]$ is isomorphic with $({\bf C}[x]) \otimes_{\bf C} ({\bf C}[y])$.  But the tensor products **over ${\bf R}$** cannot coincide, because already ${\bf C} \otimes_{\bf R} {\bf C}$ has zero divisors.  For example, $1 \otimes 1 \neq \pm \phantom. i \otimes i$ but $(1 \otimes 1)^2 = (i \otimes i)^2$, so $1 \otimes 1 \pm \phantom. i \otimes i$ are complementary zero divisors, which can then be found in $({\bf C}[x]) \otimes_{\bf R} ({\bf C}[y])$ too.

For the general question, I don't know, but you probably want to ask not just about an isomorphism but about one *induced by the morphisms $f,g,h$* — else there can be "coincidental" isomorphisms.  For example, in general a complex vector space $V$ need not be isomorphic with $V \otimes_{\bf R} {\bf C}$, and the obvious map is not an isomorphism unless $V = \lbrace0\rbrace$, but if $V$ is infinite-dimensional there are unnatural isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to your second question.  There is a cartesian square

$$X\underset{Z}{\times} Y \to X\underset{W}{\times} Y$$
$$\downarrow~~~~~~~~~~~~\downarrow$$
$$Z ~~\to ~~Z\underset{W}{\times} Z$$

where the bottom arrow is the diagonal map.  Then the top arrow is an isomorphism if (but not only if) the bottom arrow is.  Of course, if you are asking when the top two objects are abstractly isomorphic, rather than isomorphic through this particular map, there's unlikely to be a reasonable answer.

Comment: And the bottom is an isomorphism iff $Z \to W$ is an monomorphism.